# WebDriver nonsense

Tags: java, oop, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not an OOP guru and maybe there is something deeper that I am not getting, but here is what bothers me a lot:

I don't see any reason why ALL examples and tutorials for `Selenium WebDriver` are using `WebDriver` objects, example:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

In the example above, we need to add more code for casting the `WebDriver` to `TakesScreenshot`. Why do this when we can just use the `FirefoxDriver` object directly:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

All driver objects(except for GhostDriver) implement ALL `WebDriver` methods + eventually some more in addition. So, basically I can use `FirefoxDriver` or `ChromeDriver` ANYWHERE a `WebDriver` objects is needed, because they implement the `WebDriver` interface indirectly(all drivers inherit from `RemoteDriver`, which implements the `WebDriver` interface), right?

So, why not just use the 'real' drivers instead of creating them as `WebDriver` and then complicate the code with castings and so on?

Can you give me any practical example when it is better to use `WebDriver` instead of `FirefoxDriver`(for example)?

Comment: That basically boils down to why interfaces should be used. In your concrete example it might not make much sense but assume you'd want to configure which driver should actually be used without having to rebuild. You might have a class `DriverProvider` with a method like `WebDriver getConfiguredDriver()` which returns whatever is configured. Then you'd just do something `WebDriver driver = DriverProvider.getConfiguredDriver();` and be done. If you want to add a `SafariDriver` later you'd just add a different configuration but you'd not have to change the rest of your code.

Comment: "Can you give me any practical example when it is better to use WebDriver instead of FirefoxDriver(for example)?" When you want to run the same test on firefox and chrome.

Comment: @Thomas I see your point. So, I guess the conclusion is: If I use simple straightforward scripts/programs there is no point of coding against interfaces, but if I am building some kind of a framework using Selenium, then I need to code against interfaces. Do you agree?

Comment: @CuriousGuy You can use the real types if you want to. Eventually you'll encounter a situation where you'll think "man I should've coded to interfaces all along, now I'll need to rewrite all this". Then you'll have a valuable learning experience.

Comment: You _could_ do it that way, especially if you'd need casts that could fail otherwise. But in general it's best to get used to using interfaces, especially if they provide for all you need. There are often examples where people use `ArrayList list = new ArrayList();` (I left out the generics on purpose) where `List list = new ArrayList();` would be work as well. In simple cases both versions are ok but those cases might get more complex over time so you might be better off using interfaces where possible/available.

Comment: Note that in my previous comment I used "available", i.e. there is a trap that should be avoided and doing so might require some experience: you don't always need interfaces and using interfaces in inappropriate situations might be a case of overengineering, e.g. if you only have one implementation anyways (and it's very unlikely you'll ever have a second) and you're not writing code that needs to interface with others (aka API). However, it's hard to provides rules of when to provide and use interfaces and when not - experience is the key here. When in doubt: use interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

@CuriousGuy, here is an example here you need to instantiate driver object based on the configuration ( passes as parameter) on testNG suite to test the UAT in different browser.
TestNG suite

```
<suite parallel="test" Thread-count=2>
<test>
    <parameter name="browser" value="FF"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="package.MyClassname"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test>
    <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="package.MyClassname1"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

We are selecting the browser object dynamically ( polymorphism concept of OOP )

```
class TestInit{
WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"browser"})
public void intBowser(String browser){
    switch(browser){
        case "FF" :
            driver = new FireforDriver();
            break;
        case "Chrome":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrone.driver","path to your chromeDriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;
        default:
            Logger.log("No available Driver");
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.seleniumhq.org/");
}
@AfterClass
public void cleanup(){
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
}

class Myclassname extends TestInit {
@Test
public void yourTestMethod(){
    // Dynamically selected driver object will be available here. 
}
}
```

Hope that, WebDriver is not nonsense, it makes full sense :) in practical use.